# Loading and checking image from local disk in C#

Tags: c#, .net, image

i'm trying to load image from local disk, and it's working. But my problem is that i'd like to check if image is available in folder, and if not - then MessageBox.Show("No image!");

Loading image:

```
 Bitmap bitmap1 = new Bitmap(@"Documentation\\Pictures\\"+table[8]+".jpg");
 pictureBox.Image=bitmap1;
```

Comment: You shouldn't combine `@` with `\\ `.

Comment: And you should also Validate if a File is name Picutre.png but it's not a Picutre ,search for specific Exception !

Comment: When you use the `@` symbol, you can use a path just as it appears on the explorer. You no longer have to escape the slashes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) method to check whether a given file exists:

```
var file = Path.ChangeExtension(table[8], ".jpg");
var fullPath = Path.Combine(@"Documentation\Pictures", file);
if (!File.Exists(fullPath))
{
    MessageBox.Show("No image!");
}
else
{
    pictureBox.Image = new Bitmap(fullPath);
}
```

Comment: In `ASP.NET` it better be `Server.MapPath("Documentation/Pictures")` otherwise it will look for the files in the system folder of Windows.. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, yeah, absolutely, in fact in ASP.NET it should be: `Server.MapPath("~/Documentation/Pictures")`

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, what ASPX are you talking about? Can't see any reference in the OP about ASP.NET. Not to mention that `pictureBox` and ASP.NET, hmm...

Comment: @Darin correct - my bad. Too used to ASP.NET questions I guess! :/

Comment: @Darin: Can you elaborate on why you're using Path.ChangeExtension? Is there a specific reason?

Comment: @Sergio, it's safer, I always use file specific functions when dealing with files such as Path.Combine, Path.ChangeExtension, ... instead of string concatenations. For example if `table[8]` ends with a dot (`.`) the function will correctly handle the case whereas if you are using string concatenations you could end up with `foo..jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `File.Exists` method for testing if the file itself exists.
Note, however, that between invoking that method and invoking the method which actually loads the file, the file could already be gone. Thus, exception handling should be used nonetheless.

See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx#Y540) for further info.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
string fileName = string.Format(@"Documentation\\Pictures\\{0}.jpg",table[8]);
if(!File.Exists(fileName))
{
MessageBox.Show("No Image");
}
else
{
Picture1.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
}
```